# Xcode claims "this" is a reserved language keyword in C?

Tags: c, xcode, xcode4

I used Xcode's `Refactor > Rename` command to try and rename a method parameter `this` in C.

It's claiming `this` is a "reserved language keyword", but, to the best of my understanding, it is not.

Is this a bug in Xcode? Or am I missing something?

[image: C Reserved Language Keyword?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a reserved word in C99 but in C++98, it is.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a bug.

Even if `this` is not reserved in C, it's a very bad idea to name a variable like that.
C code can be mixed with C++. In such a case, your program won't compile.

So don't use this, even with C.

If you really want that, you can do a standard search and replace, instead of refactor. But again, bad idea.

Comment: IMO it's marginally better if your `.c` files *don't* compile as C++. If they do, then who's responsible for ensuring that they actually work (i.e. have the same behavior)? The person who compiles them as C++ probably thinks you are, but will you actually put that effort in, and test it? If not, then just make sure that the public `.h` files can be used from C++ (and so don't use `this` as a parameter name there). Don't act as if you support compiling as C++ without doing it properly. And don't bother supporting it: writing dual-language code is pretty pointless.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. If I have methods which operate on typedef'd structs and act like instance methods in other languages, I'd like to standardize on a name for that first `this` parameter. Suggestions as to an alternate name? I'm assuming Xcode will balk at `self` for similar reasons (objective-c).

Comment: It is a bug. C and C++ are not the same language, and calling `this` "a reserved language keyword" is simply false.

Comment: C and C++ are not the same language, sure... But as I said: «Even if 'this' is not reserved in C, it's a very bad idea to name a variable like that». Even if you don't care about C++, and only write C, simply remember that people may use your source code from other languages... Do not think about how you're going to use your own code. Try to think about how people may use it...

Answer (score 0):

"this" is also a keyword in Java. I don't know about Xcode 4, but you could use previous versions for Java development as well. It's possible some wires are getting crossed...

Comment: Not sure why the down vote, but I thought I'd clarify the reason for my answer. Wonder if the down-voter has the same sense of courtesy?

Comment: Well I'll +1 you because I think you're pretty much saying the same thing everyone else is - that Xcode is taking into account other languages in the "refactoring" tool. Thanks for taking the time to look at the question and  post a response!

Comment: Heh - thanks for the pity plus. ;-) It's definitely a reserved word in more than one language - my "contribution" was just that Java at least *used to be* a language Xcode supported.